# When plotting dummy variables, how can I change the 0.0,1.0 on x-axis into male female?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am using `ggplot2` to make a barplot. X-axis is a dummy variable so it shows 0.0 and 1.0 on the plot. But I want to make it more readable. For example, change the 0.0 to male, 1.0 to female.

Comment: Do you need something like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22288869/4265407

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way is to mutate the data frame column from `numeric` to `factor` type prior the plotting. See the code below:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Simulation
df <- data.frame(gender = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), country = factor(c("US", "EU", "UK", "US", "EU", "EU")))


# Mutate from numeric to factor
df_m <- df %>% as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(gender = as.factor(if_else(gender < 1, "Male", "Female")))

# Plots
ggplot(df_m, aes(gender, fill = country)) +
  geom_bar()
```

Output:
[image: barplot]

Comment: It works, thank you!